# "Next Js" No se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js

Hace poco clone este repositorio (hecho con next js) pero cuando escribo el comando "yarn start" me da este error:

```
> example@0.9.12 start
> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true react-scripts start

"SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
 programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Este es el repositorio sdk/packages/example : https://github.com/rarible/sdk/tree/master/packages/example
Instale todo como dice en el README pero no solo este comando sino que a veces son los demás comandos que me indica el mismo archivo:

1. Clone repository
2. Install dependencies and build sdk. Execute in the root folder:

   ```bash
   yarn && yarn bootstrap && yarn build-all
   ```
3. Start the application in development mode:

   ```bash
   cd packages/example
   yarn start
   ```

Si quito el SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true del package.json me da el siguiente error el cual ya segui los pasos pero sigo sin pasar de ese error:

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to 
fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a 
dependency:

"jest": "26.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it         
automatically.
However, a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Cristian\LINETOYS\sdk\node_modules\jest 
(version: 27.5.1)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to- 
debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true 
to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other 
issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact 
order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in 
your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the 
package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the 
above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting 
which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if 
C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Cristian\LINETOYS\sdk\node_modules\jest is 
outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in 
your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected 
react-scripts) installed jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in 
your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to 
proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We 
hope you find them helpful!
```

Comment: en tu package.json no tenes next en ningun lado. Yo tengo un proyecto en next con la misma version de react que tenes (17.0.2) y tengo ``"next": "^12.0.0"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucione el error:

1. Elimine el `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` del package.json
2. Añadi el `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` a un archivo `.env` ,en la carpeta raiz de mi proyecto.
3. Despues me dio otro error que solucione cambiando mi version de node v17 a node v16 y con `NVM` que cambia la version solo en mi proyecto.

Answer (score 2):

Anda al `package.json` en el directorio raíz de la aplicación y busca la opción `scripts` y remueve `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` de todos los scripts:

Debe quedar así:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "verify": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
```

## EDIT 1:

Borra el `package-lock.json`. OJO: NO BORRES EL `package.json` sino el `package-lock`. Borra la carpeta `node_modules`, ve al `package.json` y elimina `"jest": "26.6.0"` y dale `npm install`. Después de eso posicionate en el root del proyecto e instala jest `npm install jest`. Si eso no funciona entonces intenta agregar de nuevo `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` a los script de tu `package.json`.

Comment: Lo intente pero despues me da un error de compatibilidad entre un modulo, el error lo agregue a la pregunta.

Comment: @CamiloSW edité el comentario. Intenta hacer lo del Edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

Págalo por adelantado
El decir “gracias” es apreciado pero no contesta la pregunta. En lugar de hacer eso, vota a favor todas las respuestas que más te ayudaron. Si estas respuestas te fueron útiles, considera ser agradecido en una manera mas constructiva - por contribuir tus propias respuestas a preguntas que tus colegas aquí han preguntado.

¿Tienes el mismo problema?
¿No hay respuesta a cierta pregunta y tienes el mismo problema? Ayúdanos a encontrar una solución. Investiga el problema y aporta los resultados de tu investigación con información adicional como una respuesta parcial. De esa forma, aunque no se obtenga una respuesta, la persona siguiente tendrá más con que hacerle frente al desafío. Podrás también votar a favor la pregunta u ofrecer una recompensa para que la pregunta reciba más atención.

Contesta la pregunta
Lee la pregunta cuidadosamente. ¿Qué es lo que se está preguntando específicamente? Asegurarte de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a esto. Y si no, provee una alternativa viable. La respuesta puede ser “no hagas eso” pero debe también incluir “trata esto en vez”. Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta. La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores.

Ofrece contexto para los enlaces
Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a